# How to add/edit policies.json of firefox snap

Tags: firefox, 22.04

Since `/usr/lib/firefox` is under `/snap` now, which is read-only, how can I create a policies.json file for firefox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [README in the policy templates repository](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md) you can put your `policies.json` file in `/etc/firefox/policies`.

This also works with a snappy Firefox. Tested on a clean Kubuntu 22.04 VM.

Comment: I also verified the policies were recognised (and partially) loaded from that position (on Ubuntu 22.10). However, the root ca that was referred to in that `policies.json` was not added to the snap Firefox version. It is added by the apt version of Firefox.